# Remove element of a vector in files C++

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I've been trying to delete an element from my vector using `fstream` for a while. I made a post before about this and I applied the advice from you guys but still I'm not getting my program to delete the element of my vector.
I can creat and re write my .txt file into another one but I can't make my code to delete the element. I think I've been having problems with `ios::truc` or `ios::out`. Any suggestion ? feel free to try my code and check it out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


void Menu()
{
    cout << "******************" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Add student" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Delete student" << endl;
    cout << "3 - All students" << endl;
    cout << "******************" << endl;
}

struct School
{
    string Name;
    string remove;
    int Ages;
    int Option;
};

int main()
{
    School Students;
    vector <string> Names;

    ofstream Myfile("practiceFile.txt", ios::app);

    if(!Myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
    }

    if(Myfile.is_open())
    {
        Menu();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Option: ";
        cin >> Students.Option;
        cin.ignore();

        if(Students.Option == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            getline(cin, Students.Name);
            Names.push_back(Students.Name);

            for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
            {
                Myfile << Names[i] << endl;
            }
        }    
    
        if(Students.Option == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            getline(cin, Students.remove);
            
            for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
            {
                if(Students.remove == Names[i])
                {
                    auto itr = find(Names.begin(), Names.end(), Students.remove);
                    if(itr != Names.end())
                    {
                        Names.erase(itr);
                        Myfile << Names[i] << endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


    ofstream TempFile("practiceFile_temp.txt", ios::trunc|ios::out);

    if(TempFile.is_open())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
        {
            TempFile << Names[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    TempFile.close();
    Myfile.close();
 
    remove("practiceFile.txt");

    rename("practiceFile_temp.txt", "practiceFile.txt");
    
    string line;
    ifstream NewFile("practiceFile.txt", ios::in);
    
    while(NewFile >> line)
    {
        if(Students.Option == 3)
        {
            cout << line << endl;
        }         
    }
}
```

Actually, if you compile my code you won't be able to save strings into the file. But when I delete this part of my code (here below) At leats I'm able to save strings into the file but not delete them. As I said before, I think I'm not using `ios::trunc|ios::out` correct. Thanks!

```
    ofstream TempFile("practiceFile_temp.txt", ios::trunc|ios::out);

    if(TempFile.is_open())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
        {
            TempFile << Names[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    TempFile.close();
    Myfile.close();
 
    remove("practiceFile.txt");

    rename("practiceFile_temp.txt", "practiceFile.txt");
```

**UPDATE:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


void Menu()
{
    cout << "******************" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Add student" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Delete student" << endl;
    cout << "******************" << endl;
}

struct School
{
    string Name;
    string remove;
    int Ages;
    int Option;
};

int main()
{
    School Students;
    vector <string> Names;

    ifstream NewFile("practiceFile.txt");

    string line;
    while(getline(NewFile, line))
    {
        cout << line << endl;
    }

    ofstream Myfile("practiceFile.txt", ios::app);

    if(!Myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
    }

    if(Myfile.is_open())
    {
        Menu();
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Option: ";
        cin >> Students.Option;
        cin.ignore();

        if(Students.Option == 1)
        {
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            getline(cin, Students.Name);
            Names.push_back(Students.Name);
        }    
    
        if(Students.Option == 2)
        {
            cout << "Enter name: ";
            getline(cin, Students.remove);
            
            for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
            {
                if(Students.remove == Names[i])
                {
                    Names.erase(Names.begin() + i);
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
        {
            Myfile << Names[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    ofstream TempFile("practiceFile_temp.txt", ios::trunc);

    if(TempFile.is_open())
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < Names.size(); i++)
        {
            TempFile << Names[i] << endl;
        }
    }

    TempFile.close();
    Myfile.close();
 
    remove("practiceFile.txt");

    rename("practiceFile_temp.txt", "practiceFile.txt");
}
```

Comment: Note: If you are going to iterate through the `vector` looking for a match, there is no need for `find` because you have already found the element to remove. You could `Names.erase(Names.begin() + i);` or loop and call `find` until find finds nothing. Better would be to use [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) if you want all matching names to be removed. Still mentally parsing the code, so I'm not sure what your actual problem is yet.

Comment: Good advice, I'll change that in my code. I think my problem is into `ios` but I'm not sure. I've tried many things, I've changed a lot my code and I couldn't make to delete the element of my vector into the file. @user4581301

Comment: I think part of the problem is the code never reads the input file. I recommend that you stop writing code for now and figure out how you will read the data from the file into the `vector`.

Comment: Actually If I delete the part of my code when I create the new file `TempFile` and I rename that file with my old file. If I do that, I can add strings into the file and read the file. I don't get what you mean, could you please develop a bit more? @user4581301

Comment: practiceFile.txt is never opened for reading. Anything you write to the file is never read into `Names`, so every run of the program starts as though the file is empty.

Comment: In the end of the code when I call  `ifstream NewFile("practiceFile.txt", ios::in);`. Doesn't this supposed to read line by line into the file ? @user4581301

Comment: Reading the file at the end isn't effective. You need to read the file into `Names` at the beginning of the program for it to be useful.

Comment: I've changed the code, now it's reading in the beggining. Would you suggest to use a temporaly file and then rewrite that file ? I don't know what more to do to make the vector erase the element and so on in the file. @user4581301

Comment: The latter half looks more-or-less correct. You write a temporary file and then replace the current file with the temporary. I'd protect `TempFile << Names[i] << endl;` with an if statement to ensure it was successful, and leave out the `|ios::out` when opening because `ofstream` automatically adds `out` (same with ifstreams and `in`), but those two shouldn't change what you are seeing.

Comment: I did everything you suggested plus all the pages I've read about it, still nothing. I don't know what is happening with my code, I'm getting crazy. Thanks for your help. @user4581301

Comment: Please update the code in the question with where you are at now. No point to working from obsolete code.

Comment: I just updated the code. Can you check it out, please ? @user4581301

Comment: `while(getline(NewFile, line)) { cout << line << endl; }` reads and prints the file. You need to put it into `Names`. `while(getline(NewFile, line)) { Names.push_back(line); }` or something similar.

Comment: I changed the code and now it's copying every time that I run my code all the strings twice. So If I add my name for example, the next time I run my code I see it twice and so on. Anyway, I still don't know where is my issue. Have you run my code ? @user4581301